# Error con parametro tipo DateTime en Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Buen dia.

Tengo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi consulta es la siguiente:

`let   Source = Sql.Database("Servidor","BaseDeDatos",[Query = select * from as tabla t where t.Date between '"&DateTime.ToText(StartTimeParameter,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' and '"&DateTime.ToText(EndTimeParameter,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"']) in Source`

al salir del transfordata es donde me sale el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a los parametros le asigno los valores con una tabla calculada de la siguiente manera, hice una tabla para cada parametro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el campo de relaciones le asigno los valores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los parametros estan configurados de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: No se entiende lo suficiente. Podrias ir al editor avanzado copiar las primeras líneas de donde está la consulta, editar aquí tu pregunta y pegar ese código?

Comment: @RogerTorné Ya edite la pregunta.

Comment: No veo problema, pero en la consulta haces referencia a `StartDate` y no a `StartTimeParameter`

Comment: @RogerTorné agregue mas detalles y corregi el codigo a como debe de ser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que Power BI no reconoce el parámetro de Power Query, para solucionarlo, debes cargar el parámetro.

En Power Query, botón secundario del ratón encima de cada parámetro y activas "Enable load"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias!!!